# R transforming list of lists to data frame with list number as column

Tags: r, list

What feels like a really simple question that I'm just stuck on. I'm trying to break out a list of lists into a 2-column data frame with the list number as a column.

Sample Data:

```
d <- list("1" =c("ad","af"), "2" =c("bc","bd","be"))
> d
$`1`
[1] "ad" "af"

$`2`
[1] "bc" "bd" "be"
```

Desired output:

```
ID    Value
1     ad
1     af
2     bc
2     bd
2     be
```

A for loop would do the job but I'm trying to avoid that. The `unlist` function actually accomplishes slightly more than I'd like, as it lists out in the names the list name followed by the element number:

```
unlist(d)
  11   12   21   22   23 
"ad" "af" "bc" "bd" "be"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
stack(d)
#  values ind
#1     ad   1
#2     af   1
#3     bc   2
#4     bd   2
#5     be   2
```

Comment: Amazing how simple some things are. Thank you- will mark as answer when the timer allows

Answer (score 0):

A quick way:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  mapply(function(id, vals) cbind(ID = id, Value = vals), names(d), d, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
unlist(d, use.names=FALSE)  
"ad" "af" "bc" "bd" "be"
```